# Работа с реестром C# net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

День добрый, пытаюсь изменить запись в реестре средствами C# .net 2. Вот мой код, прошу указать ошибку. Программа запускается от имени администратора, так что с правами все нормально.

```
RegistryKey saveKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters", true);
        saveKey.SetValue("DhcpNameServer", "192.168.1.10");
        saveKey.Close();
```

Comment: Ошибку выдает, или что? Может быть прав не хватает?

Comment: Нет, ошибку не выдает...но запись в реестре не изменяется, вот в чем беда...резные методы перепробовал, все равно чет не получается.

Comment: @Corle Windows x86 или x64? Значение надо поменять для x86 или для x64? Процесс запускаешь x86, x64 или Any CPU?

Comment: Я тестировал на винде 64 разрядной, но нужно естественно что бы работало везде

Comment: @Corle процесс тоже x64 запускал?

Comment: Any CPU, вроде так ставил

Comment: А чем вы проверяете? У 64-битной Windows как бы два реестра, 32-битный и 64-битный. Если вы запускаете 64-битный процесс, а затем проверяете при помощи 32-битного regedit.exe, вы увидите разную картину.

Comment: И да, лучше использовать `using` вместо ручного закрытия ключа

Comment: нифига инфа, слушайте, можете помочь составить программу, что бы везде в реестре записи менялись?

Comment: Попробуйте помониторить действия с реестром при помощи Process Monitor, возможно запись отрабатывает нормально, но Windows может редиректить запись в другие ветки.

Comment: @VladD а разве к SYSTEM это относиться? Может это только для SOFTWARE? В x64 для SOFTWARE есть корневой для x64 и Wow6432Node для x86.

Comment: Вы пробовали после `SetValue`, сразу делать `GetValue`, и выводить это значение.
Я так понимаю это системный параметр, Вы уверены что система его не меняет обратно после ваших манипуляции? Советую всё заключить в блок `try catch`, и смотреть точно ли что-то не catch'иться, некоторые ошибки могут быть "съедены" визуал студией. Пройдитесь дебагером, внимательно смотря за окном IntellTrace.

Comment: @MaLS: Ваша правда ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: В коде ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу ошибок в коде.

Вот мой вариант:

```
public static class RegistryKeyExtensions
{
    public static RegistryKey OpenOrCreateSubKey(this RegistryKey key,
        string name, bool writable)
    {
        Contract.Requires(key != null);

        return key.OpenSubKey(name, writable) ?? key.CreateSubKey(name);
    }
}

// Использование
using (RegistryKey saveKey = 
     Registry.LocalMachine.OpenOrCreateSubKey(keyPath, true))
{
    saveKey.SetValue(valueName, 42, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    Console.WriteLine("Initial value:" + saveKey.GetValue(valueName));

    saveKey.SetValue(valueName, "142");
    Console.WriteLine("New value:" + saveKey.GetValue(valueName));
}
```

Вывод:

```
Initial value:42
New value:142
```

Так что, если и есть проблема, то в чем-то другом, а не в этом коде.

Comment: [`RegistryKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) поддерживает `IDisposable`, так что я бы использовал `using` (для тех, кто скопипастит код).

Comment: @VladD обновил код.

Comment: О, так выглядит намного симпатичнее.

Answer (score 0):

По реестру не скажу,  но эту же задачу можно решить, запустив через `Process.Run()` нужную команду `netsh` или `ipconfig`
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782087/c-sharp-enable-disable-dhcp)

Answer (score 0):

Разрядность операционной системы и компиляции не имеет значения.
Попробуйте удалить этот ключ реестра. А потом внести его этим кодом. После `saveKey.SetValue` проверьте методом `GetValueNames()` наличие данного ключа.
З.Ы. Да и не забываем выполнить метод `Flush()`